# Binary string length mod 64

Tags: c#, winforms

After reading binary file and turn to hex and the length size is 16384 need to mod 64 to make divided 16384 into 256 string.

i have try using list to store but the list append in once, might be something wrong with my loop.

```
list<string)test = new list<string>test();
foreach(byte b in hexArray)
{
   hexstring += string.Format("{0:x2}",b);
   int length = hexstring.length /64;  //total length will have 16384

    if(length == 64)
    {
       for(int ix= 0; ix <= length; ix++)
       {
            test.add(hexstring);
       }
    }
}
```

Expected result:

abe12112121212.....  (64)

21212212sadada.....  (64)

totally will have (256) string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're appending `hexstring` infinitely. I think you should set `hexstring` null or empty after checking length and also you don't need to `for` loop to add string into List.

```cs
foreach (byte b in hexArray) {
    // If you want to print 64 characters per each hexstring
    // you can simply check length > 0 && length % 64 == 0
    if (hexstring.Length > 0 && (hexstring.Length % 64) == 0) {
        test.Add(hexstring);
        hexstring = string.Empty;
    }
}

// Print rest of hexstring (if exists)
if (hexstring.Length > 0) {
    test.Add(hexstring);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your explain, thanks for pointing out my problem.